# How to compare URL patterns in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT to convert my XML into a modified XML. I want to check a condition: where headline points to a non-pdf endpoint, do something. Below is my XML:

```
<vce>
    <form>
        <headlineURL>
            <a href="http://www.example.com/bin/internal-application.pdf" />
        </headlineURL>
    </form>
    <form>
        <headlineURL>
             <a href="http://www.demo.com" />
        </headlineURL>
    </form>
    <form>
        <headlineURL>
             <a href="http://www.demo-live.in" />
        </headlineURL>
    </form>
</vce>
```

What should I specify in the when condition in XSLT? I want to run a condition where headlineURL contains a non-pdf endpoint(eg "http://www.demo.com", ""http://www.demo-live.in")

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test= ...>
     <!-- Do something -->
   </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Actually, I am using IBM Watson Explorer to convert the XML.  Here is the link: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8NLW_10.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.dataexpl.engine.doc/c_xml-xsl-intro.html .They haven't specified the version of XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT-1.0 code does check if the inputs `headlineURL/a/@href`s do end with the string `.pdf`. The check is *case-sensitive* and only checks for `.pdf` and *not* `.PDF`, so I'd recommend to add a case-neutralization-template before the check if necessary.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />                <!-- output data as XML -->
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />           <!-- remove unnecessary spaces in output -->

  <xsl:template match="/vce/form/headlineURL">
    <xsl:variable name="doExec">             <!-- set variable with predicate -->
      <xsl:call-template name="ends-with">   <!-- check if input ends-with '.pdf' -->
        <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="a/@href" />
        <xsl:with-param name="ends" select="'.pdf'" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="$doExec != 'true'">
      <xsl:value-of select="a/@href" />: No PDF!!!     <!-- replace this line with the desired output -->
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- XSLT 1.0 version of the function 'ends-with' -->
  <xsl:template name="ends-with">
    <xsl:param name="txt" />
    <xsl:param name="ends" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($txt, string-length($txt) - string-length($ends) +1) = $ends" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```